# Laravel | How to perform search with multiple attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating property website and i am doing search with number of attributes, but the problem is that in search controller i have very large code and its very difficult to handle, is there any other solution exist in laravel?

```
$list_property = Listing_property::where([
        ['property_type', $request['property_type']],
        ['city', $request['city']],
        ['location', $request['location']],
        ['property_area_type', $request['property_area_type']],
        ['property_size', $request['property_size']],
        ['price', $min],
        ['price', $max]
    ])
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(21);
```

[image]

Comment: show your code and what steps you have taken so far.

Comment: how can i show a large code here? After Click search button  $list_property = Listing_property::where([['property_type', $request['property_type']],['city', $request['city']], ['location', $request['location']],
            ['property_area_type', $request['property_area_type']], ['property_size', $request['property_size']], ['price',$min], ['price',$max]])
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(21);

Comment: Edit your question to show the code in a nice formatted way and only include relevant code.

Comment: I understand your question. I give you an example, how to do it. Its just an example, in this method you can make search on multiole column with  just a few code

Comment: show your code for answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to search multiple column :

```
public function search(Request $request){

    $query = $request->search;
    
    $users = DB::table('users');        

   if($query){
      $users = $users->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%");
    }

    if($request->city){
      $users = $users->where('city',$request->city);
    }

    if($request->town){
      $users = $users->where('town', $request->town);
    }

   if($request->unit){
      $users = $users->where('unit', $request->unit);
    }

    $users->get();
    return view('users.index')->with('users', $users);
}
```