# Laravel eloquent real time search filtering

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a server-side searching and came up with this eloquent query...

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $data = User::with('instruments')
            ->where('user_type', 'teacher')
            ->orWhere('fname', 'like', '%' . $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('fname', 'like', $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '% ' . $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('lname', 'like', $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', '% ' . $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('email', 'like', $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('profession', 'like', '%' . $request->term . '%' )
            ->orWhere('profession', 'like', $request->term . '%' )
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();

        return response()->json($data);
}
```

I almost achieved what I wanted. For example, when I search `john` it gives me all the users with `john` in their name. The problem is that, tho the search is correct and knowing I declared `where('user_type', 'teacher')`, the result set still gives me users with `student` `user_type`

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243265/4575350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `OrWhere` nullifies the `user_type` condition, that's why it selects users that are not teachers when one of the `OrWhere` conditions applies.

By using a second where with a closure, it will always only select users with a `user_type` teacher:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $data = User::with('instruments')
        ->where('user_type', 'teacher')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('fname', 'like', '%' . $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('fname', 'like', $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('lname', 'like', '% ' . $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('lname', 'like', $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '% ' . $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('profession', 'like', '%' . $request->term . '%')
                ->orWhere('profession', 'like', $request->term . '%');
        })
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();

    return response()->json($data);
}
```