# Way to structure code for "Search Engine"

Tags: laravel

I'm currently putting together some code that allows for a user to search an activities table in multiple ways (i.e. if title checkbox is selected) I feel like my code looks a little messy so I wanted to come on stack overflow and ask everyone what would be the best way to make this code more elegant? I'm just looking for ways to improve, have more readable code, and have a better structure for it.

```
    if (request('name')){
        $name = request('name');
        $user = User::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();

        if (request('title') == 1) {
            $activities = Activity::with('activity')->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
                $query->where('threads.user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->where('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->get();
            dd($activities);
        } else {
            $activities = Activity::with('activity')->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
                $query->where('threads.user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->where('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->orWhereHas('reply', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
                $query->where('replies.user_id', '=', $user->id)
                    ->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->get();
            dd($activities);
        }
    } else {
        if (request('title') == 1) {
            $activities = Activity::with('activity')->where('user_id', $user->id)->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search, $user) {
                $query->where('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->get();
            dd($activities);
        } else {
            $activities = Activity::with('activity')->whereHas('thread', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('threads.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('threads.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->orWhereHas('reply', function ($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            })->get();
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: This can help [Laravel | How to perform search with multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63243265/4575350)

Comment: You could use the query builder's `when` and `unless` methods as well as define some query scopes in your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the query builder's `when` and `unless` methods as well as define some query scopes in your models so your end result could look something like this

```php
$user = request('name') ? User::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail() : null;
$title = request('title') == 1;

$activities = Activity::with('activity')->search($search, $user, $title)->get();
```

```
# Activity model
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, ?$search = null, ?User $user = null, bool $title = false)
{
    if (!$search)
        return $query;
    else
        return $query->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('user_id', $user->id))
                     ->whereHas('thread', fn($thread) => $thread->search($search, $user))
                     ->unless($title, fn($q) => $q->orWhereHas('reply', fn($reply) => $reply->search($search, $user)));
}
```

```
# Thread model
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, ?string $search = null, ?User $user = null)
{
    if (!$search)
        return $query;
    else
        return $query->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('threads.user_id', $user->id))
                     ->where(fn($q) => $q->where('threads.title', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                         ->orWhere('threads.body', 'LIKE', "%$search%"));
}
```

```
# Reply model
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, ?string $search = null, ?User $user = null)
{
    if (!$search)
        return $query;
    else
        return $query->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('replies.user_id', $user->id))
                     ->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
}
```

Scopes are basically reusable queries. You can define them at a global level (for all models) or at a local level (this is what I've done here).

[Local Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

With them, I've moved nearly all the query related logic to the models but if you prefer, you could still write it all in the controller.

Using the scopes I defined,

```php
$activities = Activity::with('activity')
    // call Activity Model's search scope
    ->search($search, $user, $title)
    ->get();
```

translates to

```js
$activities = Activity::with('activity')
    ->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('user_id', $user->id))
    // call Thread model's search scope in whereHas('thread', ...) closure
    ->whereHas('thread', fn($thread) => $thread->search($search, $user))
    // call Reply model's search scope in whereHas('reply', ...) closure
    ->unless($title, fn($q) => $q->orWhereHas('reply', fn($reply) => $reply->search($search, $user)))
    ->get();
```

which in turn translates to

```js
$activities = Activity::with('activity')
    ->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('user_id', $user->id))
    ->whereHas('thread', function ($thread) use ($search, $user) {
        $thread->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('threads.user_id', $user->id))
               ->where(fn($q) => $q->where('threads.title', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                                   ->orWhere('threads.body', 'LIKE', "%$search%"));
    })
    ->unless($title, fn($q) => $q->orWhereHas('reply', function ($reply) use ($search, $user) {
        $reply->when($user, fn($q) => $q->where('replies.user_id', $user->id))
              ->where('replies.body', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
    }))
    ->get();
```

The `$title` variable could be inlined at this point. `->unless(request('title') == 1, ...)`

- [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses): `when()`, `unless()`.
- [Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping): `where(fn($q) => ...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting this together, but at the moment, my level (i know this sounds like an excuse, and it probably is, maybe it's just my style), the scope filtering isn't really clicking with my understanding. Could you please perhaps dumb it down a little so that scopes aren't required? Thank you I really appreciate it. I will still try to understand this code, but I don't understand it right now.

Comment: Is each of the scopes being called on the activity model at the controller? When are the scopes in the Reply model and Thread model one called?

Comment: @user123 I've edited the answer to explain in more detail. The scopes in the Reply and Thread controller are called in the whereHas closures, which were located in the Activity scope

Comment: Hi There, I decided to try the code with the filtering -- but somehow when I change the Activity scopeSearch to:

Comment: return $query->when($user, function ($q) use ($user) { $q->where('user_id', $user->id); })
                         ->whereHas('thread', function ($thread) use ($search, $user) { $thread->search($search, $user); })
                         ->orWhereHas('reply', function ($reply) use ($search, $user) { $reply->search($search, $user); })
                         ->unless($title == 1, function ($q) use ($search, $user) { $q->orWhereHas('thread', function ($thread) use ($search, $user) { $thread->search($search, $user); });});,

Comment: it just returns everything

Comment: The `whereHas('thread', ...)` is repeated. If search evaluates to null, then the scopes just returns the query. Maybe that's what's happening? Does `dd(Activity::search(...)->toSql());` show the query you expected?

Comment: I don't understand why when I add the ->orWhereHas('reply') part to the Activity scope it doesn't return the replies too. I'll try to read the code again and see what's missing.

Comment: Oh I found it, it was the closure in the replies scope

Comment: One other thing i'm running into is that when I put the Activity Scope code: unless($title == FALSE), it returns the correct, that is, it also returns the replies. Shouldn't it be when $title == TRUE it returns the correct values? I'm kind of confused because it's reverse logic

Comment: So a little strange, when I put request('title') instead of $request->title, the boolean logic for title works correctly.

Comment: `unless(condition, closure)` is the same as `when(!condition, closure)`. It's also possible to pass a third parameter. `when(condition, closure1, closure2)`. Closure2 will execute if the `condition` evaluates to `false`. It's like an `else`.

Comment: so I could just as well use ->when instead of ->unless and it would still be the equivalent as if I had used ->unless? I find the logic pattern for unless a little confusing... It's like I'd expect ->unless($title == TRUE) to be unless $title is checked, but instead the way it evaluates is opposite of what I'd expect.

Comment: Yes, you could just use when.

Comment: Well this was very informative IGP, thank you for weighing in, I learned quite a bit from this exercise :)